# How to have two different ways of indexing the same axis in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I would like to be able to have two column indices for the same axis simultaneously for a pandas DataFrame. The objects in the indices would be of different types, one enum and one string, so that both types could be used to index without ambiguity. Phrased differently it would be like a MultiIndex without the hierarchy. The aim would be that each column should have a name and an indexable column type.

I want to be able to do both of the following index operations on the same DataFrame:

```py
df['NAME']
df[MyType.FirstName]      # MyType is an Enum
```

I haven't found any obvious ways to do this. One way could be to use one single index that use objects of a 'combined' class that overrides the comparison operators differently depending on the types given. Is this the way to go or is there a better way?

```py
class Combination:
    def __init__(self, value1, value2):
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, str):
            return self.value1 == other
        else:
            return self.value2 == other

    # etc if other operators are needed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK pandas has no provision for that. A simple way is to use a translation dictionary:

```
trans = {MyType.FirstName: 'NAME', ...}

df[trans[MyType.FirstName]]   # same as df['NAME']
```

Comment: This way you'd need to pair each DataFrame with its translation dictionary. It would be better if it could be built into each DataFrame object.

Comment: As I have already said, pandas has no provision for that. You will have to live with it.